# how to remove comma(,) from splitted string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have used split function to split the string in javascript.
which is as,

```
   test= event_display1.split("#");
```

This works perfectly and giving me output as,

```
   Event Name : test1
   Location : test, test, test
   ,
   Event Name : test2
   Location : test, test, test
   ,
```

But i want my output as

```
   Event Name : test1
   Location : test, test, test

   Event Name : test2
   Location : test, test, test
```

When i split the value it set comma after the character which i have used as split character.

How can i remove this comma from my output value?

Comment: showing the original input and code would be even better

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default the `.toString()` of an `Array` will use comma as its delimiter, just use the following:

```
var str = test.join("");
```

Whatever you pass as the argument to `join` will be used as the delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments it would be really useful to see the input. I'll assume a structure based on your output. You could remove the commas from the array after you have split it, like this:

```
var event_display1 = "Event Name : test1#Location : test, test, test#,#Event Name : test2#Location : test, test, test#,#";
var test = event_display1.split("#");

for (var i = event_display1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   if (test[i] == ",") {
          //Use test.slice(i, 1); if you want to get rid of the item altogether
          test[i] = "";
   }
}
```

rwz's answer of trimming the string before splitting it is definitely simpler. That could be tweaked for this example like this:

```
event_display1 = event_display1.replace(/#,#/g, "##")
var test = event_display1.split("#");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your output string consists of multiple strings (using \n character), you can remove unwanted commas with this code:
`myString.replace(/\,(?:\n|$)/g, "\n")`